# How to a simulation program that stops executing before or at simulated 24 hours

Tags: c, for-loop, simulation

There is a 500 gallon tank of water that has been used to
hold fish to be Fish Fry in 24 hours. The tank as a leak that is losing water at the rate of 10% of the remaining water every hour. How do I fix my code to make it stop executing after 24 hours or after the tank volume hits 100 gallon. For some reason, I can't seem to wrap my head around a for loop.

```
int main()
{
    double add, gal = 500, vol, newVol, hour;

    printf("Please enter additional water added per hour: ");
    scanf("%f", &add);

    for (int hour = 0; hour <= 24; hour++)
    {
        vol = gal * 0.90 + add;
    }
    printf("The volume is %f gallons after %d hours. \n", &vol, &hour);

}
```

Comment: Simple: Note the timestamp in the beginning, and at certain interval, keep checking the timestamp.

Comment: Add a condition in your loop to check for the volume as well?

Comment: Add `if (vol >= 100.0) break;` to the loop? Although I do not understand the "100" if the tank has a capacity of 500 gallons...

Comment: Or initialize `vol = 0.0` when declared and then `for (int hour = 0; hour <= 24 && vol >= 100; hour++)` (that's presuming you want to keep frying until the oil volume falls below 100 gal - adjust test as needed) **AND** `&vol, &hour);` should be `vol, hour);`. (no `'&'` sign for printing)

Comment: Which means you don't have compiler warnings sufficiently enable. For gcc/clang add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your compile string, for VS add `/W3`, and do not accept code until it compiles without warning.

Comment: I edited the title to talk about simulation, since your code doesn't seem to use real time, and looks like a simualtion. If this is actually supposed to use real time, please roll back.

Comment: @hyde -- I think your safe, nothing about the fish having to be done by 5:00.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your program:

- you should include `<stdio.h>`
- The `scanf()` conversion specification for `double` type is `%lf`, not `%f`.
- You should test the return value of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior on invalid input.
- The loop iterates 25 times instead of 24.
- the expression `vol = gal * 0.90 + add;` to update the volume is incorrect: you should update `gal` or use just `vol`. Furthermore, if the water is added at the beginning of each hour, it should be `vol = (gal + add) * 0.90;`, but the tank cannot hold more than 500 gallons. If the water is added at the end of each hour, you should test if it reaches 100 gallons before adding more water.
- you do not test the limit of `100` gallons
- the `printf` format is incorrect, as well as the arguments: it should be `printf("The volume is %f gallons after %f hours. \n", vol, hour);` or better `printf("The volume is %f gallons after %d hours. \n", vol, hour);` and `hour` should be defined as `int`.
- `main` should return `0`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double add, gal = 500, vol;
    int hour;

    printf("Please enter additional water added per hour: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &add) != 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (vol = gal, hour = 1; hour <= 24; hour++) {
        vol = vol * 0.90;
        if (vol <= 100)
            break;
        /* water is added at the end of each hour */
        vol += add;
        /* the tank cannot hold more than 500 gallons */
        if (vol > gal)
            vol = gal;
    }
    printf("The volume is %f gallons after %d hours.\n", vol, hour);
    return 0;
}
```

You might want to compute the exact time where the volume drops to 100 gallons, but it is more complicated.

Comment: In C (since C99 I think), you don't need `return` in main, and if it is missing then return value 0 is expected.

Comment: @hyde: that's correct for C99 and later, the committee hacked the C specification to ensure sloppy legacy code would implicitly return 0 if `main` leaves without a return statement. Making this implicit `return 0;` explicit is good style.

Comment: How can `vol` be `<= 100` since above `vol = gal * 0.90` and `gal` is constant in the loop? Shouldn't that be `for (vol=gal, hour...` and `vol *= 0.9` below?

Comment: @RingØ: indeed you are correct! there is always one more bug :)

Comment: @chqrlie I suppose that is matter of opinion. In C being explicit is a thing (compared to C++ for example, where constructors can do an unknown amount of processing in copies, etc). OTOH, every line which brings nothing to the code is a bad line, just clutter. I think correct solution would be to change return type to `void main()`, since that is allowed in C (IIRC).

Comment: @hyde: `void main()` is not allowed by the C Standard. The explicit `return 0;` means *return success to the executing environment*. Making some implicit things explicit is a matter of style and IMHO clarity. For example `char *p = NULL;` is preferable over `char *p = 0;` which is exactly equivalent but less explicit.

Comment: @chqrlie After some googling, it seems C standard allows implementation defined main signatures (unlike C++, I believe). This is probably what I remembered. It's beside the point though, as portability breaking stuff obviously shouldn't be used without compelling reason.

Comment: @hyde: **C19 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup** *The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters: `int main(void) { /* ... */ }` or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared): `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }` or equivalent or in some other implementation-defined manner.*

Comment: *Other implementation defined manner* usually refer to adding a third argument un unix systems such as: `int main(int argc, char **argv, char** envp) {...}`. I cannot think of any C environment where `void main()` would cause problems, but it is nevertheless incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, this is only a simulation that doesn't need to be real time.

Simply adding the line:

```
if (vol <= 100) break;
```

So it exits the for loop.

On a side note, there is certainly other errors in your code. For example, the `vol` will always be the same value. Also your variable `hour` used for the `for` loop is not the same one that you are using outside (in the `printf` for example). You should do something like that to make it work:

```
vol = gal
for (hour = 0; hour <= 24; hour++)
{
    vol = vol * 0.90 + add;
    if (vol <= 100) break;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use gettimeofday() function, to get the initial time (when the process starts) and then again use gettimeofday() repeatedly to get the current time. When the difference between Current time and INitial time is 24 Hrs, break from the loop.

For reference check http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html

Comment: Well -- yes, but looping `hour = 0; hour <= 24; ...` does it by virtue of the loop count `:)`

Comment: I don't think the question is about waiting actual 24 hours, but instead running a simulation as fast as it runs, so `gettimeofday` is not useful.